# OpenMP Shared Array Load/Store

Tags: memory, openmp

I have two questions about WRITE/READ operations on shared arrays.

1) In my program I write a different element of a given shared array at each iteration of an OpenMP-parallelized DO LOOP. Given that each iteration acts on a different part of the array and no race condition occurs, I avoided the use of CRITICAL. In a different subroutine I aldo READ different elements at each iteration. The results that I get should be right but I'm just wondering whether this is fine or I should enclose the READ/WRITE section in a CRITICAL block.

2) Generally speaking, can we say that if there is no risk of race condition as in the two cases above, the CRITICAL or ATOMIC blocks can be omitted?

Thanks in advance

Timmy

Answer (score 0):

1) So long as you are right, and different threads write to different array elements, then there will be no data races.  The straightforward approach to this is to write (pseudo-)code like this

```
!$omp parallel do
do i = 1, many
    array(i) = something ...
...
```

in which each thread gets a different set of `i` values, and therefore a different set of array elements to write to.

Reading will not cause data races.  Ill-disciplined reading may result in over-active caching and might result in poor performance.  But not data races.

2) Yes, generally speaking, if there are no data races you can avoid using `atomic` or `critical` blocks.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I meant.